# How to create a file in a mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am new to programming mac apps in Objective-C and need help with this. When I control click and drag to first responder from a button it brings up a box from which you can select some predefined functions that run when the button is clicked. On of the functions says newDocument. I was wondering if this means that it creates a new document (file) and if so how to actually make it create the file. I tried selecting newDocument but when I ran the app it said this:          `2016-03-16 15:39:57.889 Test[26619:4382721] The (null) type doesn't map to any NSDocumentClass.` My button is simply named create file and has no code attached to it, only the predefined function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you are seeing, `newDocument`, is part of the [Document Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Devpedia-CocoaApp-MOSX/DocArchitecture.html). If you wish to use it you need to study the documentation, the particular function `newDocument` creates a "document" within your app along with an associated "window" rather than a "file" *per se*.

It sounds like you really need to read the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html) to learn how to handle a mouse event, and the [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH1-SW1) to learn how to read & write files.

HTH